# Python Django - images not showing in templates

Tags: python, django

My images won't show up in my templates, but it does display a little 'frame' where the image should be displayed. I've tried several things but won't work. I have the exact same settings in my other project and it works fine there. This is what I'm seeing:

[result on localhost:8000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OptO9.png)

My settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import mimetypes

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-xxxx'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'cvapp',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'collabcenter.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'collabcenter.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

TEMPLATE_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/'),
]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

My urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from collabcenter import views
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.urls import include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static



urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('index/', views.index),
    path('', include('cvapp.urls')),
            
    ]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My base.html (base template):

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head> 
{% block title %}
<title>Welcome at CollabCenter, the heart of our cooperation!</title>
 {% endblock %}
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

{% block menu %}    
<div class="w-100 p-1" style="background-color: black">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm"><font color= "#FFFFFF"></font></div>
        <div class="col-sm"><font color= "#FFFFFF"></font></div>
        <div class="col-sm"><img src="{% static 'question_verkleind.png' %}" class="rounded float-end"></img><font color= "#FFFFFF" size="1px"><p class="text-end">CollabCenter v1.0 &emsp;</font></p></div>
        
    </div>
</div>

<div class="w-100 p-4" style="background-color: #ffffff;"><img src="{% static 'logo.png' %}"></img></div>

<div class="w-100 p-3" style="background-color: #5271ff;">
        <a href="../index/"><button type ="button" class="btn btn-light">Home</button></a>
        <a href="../item_list/"><button type ="button" class="btn btn-light">Candidates</button></a>
        <button type ="button" class="btn btn-light">Clients</button>
        <button type ="button" class="btn btn-light">Vacancies</button>
        <button type ="button" class="btn btn-light">MatchPlaza</button>
        <a href="../admin/"><button type ="button" class="btn btn-dark">My account</button></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="w-100 p-4" style="background-color: #ffffff;"></div> <!-- deze bar word alleen toegevoegd zodat de content eronder (body) altijd een height margin heeft -->
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}
<div class="w-100 p-5" style="background-color: white"></div>
<div class="w-100 p-5" style="background-color: white"></div>
<div class="w-100 p-5" style="background-color: black"></div>
{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

I have compared the settings with my other django projects and they are the same. I have searched at stackoverflow for same issues and tried all solutions but it doesn't work.

Comment: I just found out that if I add an alt text (alt="test") the alt text is displayed only, not the image and also not the 'frame' of the image. Hope this helps for a solution